# Slow data retrieval in h5py dataset of key-value strings

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

Given the following h5py file `root -> group1 -> million key,val pairs`:
Retrieving any number of datasets (Even 1) takes extremely long time (~10 seconds), and I wonder if I could insert them differently to control that behavior (I assume that the caching is too big for my use-case, but the default size is 1MB)
The behavior is as follows:

```
script A

hdf5 = h5py.File(path_to_h5py, libver='latest',mode='a')
hdf5_dataet = hdf5.create_group(name_of_dataset)
for key, val in tqdm(dataset.items()):
    hdf5_dataet.create_dataset(json.dumps(key),data=json.dumps(val))

script B

f = h5py.File(path_to_h5py,'r')
data = f[name_of_dataset]
key_example = next(data.__iter__()) ---------> This takes 10 seconds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HDF5 doesn't use key/value pairs like a Python dictionary. The data structures are more like NumPy arrays. I don't know what you are ultimately trying  to do. There is a far simpler iterator for Script B. Try this:

```
h5f = h5py.File(path_to_h5py,'r')
data = h5f[name_of_dataset]
for key_example in data:
    print (key_example)
```

Simple test added on 2020-04-25 to check I/O performance:

```
import h5py
import time

upper = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
lower = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
nums = '0123456789'

with h5py.File('SO_61417130.h5','w') as h5w:

    nrows = 16
    nrpts = 100

    #vstr_dt = h5py.string_dtype(encoding='utf-8') # for h5py 2.10.0
    vstr_dt = h5py.special_dtype(vlen=str)   # for h5py 2.9.0
    vstr_ds = h5w.create_dataset('testvstrs', (nrpts*nrows,1), dtype=vstr_dt )
    print (vstr_ds.dtype, ":", vstr_ds.shape)    

    rcnt = 0
    for cnt1 in range(nrpts) :
        for cnt2 in range(nrows) :
            vstr_ds[rcnt]= ((cnt2+1)*(upper+lower+nums))
            rcnt +=1

    print (vstr_ds.dtype, ":", vstr_ds.shape)    
    print ('done writing')

    start = time.clock()
    for cnt in range(-nrows,0,1) :
        find_str = vstr_ds[cnt] 
        print (len(find_str[0]))

    print ('Elapsed time =', (time.clock() - start) )
```

Comment: That still takes about 10 seconds to access the first element. This is the only problem, I assumed the fetching time from the dataset would be 100X faster

Comment: Reading data is basically I/O. How big is the the dataset, and row/key_example?  How much RAM?

Comment: 128GB ram, each row size is less than 1MB(string pointing to ~1000 chars), as I said, it doesn't make sense:/

Comment: If I understand, you are creating 1 dataset for each json key. Contents are strings from json values. There is only 1 string/row, right? Are they fixed or variable length? Check dtype if you don't know. Also check dataset chunk size.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. dataset chunk size is per dataset right? thus if I have 1 string/row the default chunk size (1MB) suits me no? they aren't fixed size, and relatively long.

Comment: I added some code to my previous answer to test I/O performance with variable length strings. I ran with `nrpts = 100, 100 and 10000`. Create time increased, but Access/Read time was always less than 0.002-0.004 sec. At this point, I don't have any more suggestions.

Comment: DsCpp, glad that helped. I'm curious: what did you find that solved your problem? Does iterating on the row counter (instead of the row) make a difference?

Comment: I believe I abused h5py mechanism by inserting 5 million datasets (one per key-val) instead of 1 dataset with a numpy-like array with 5 million rows. (as seen in my script, in compared to yours)

Comment: The problem now of course that I cannot query by key, rather only by index

Comment: It depends what you mean by 'query by key'. If the key is a string in one of the fields, it can be done with PyTables (aka tables). It has fast search methods to find and returns rows matching user specified criteria.